# Getting doc from Firestore in auth listener creating an infinite loop, nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Firestore every time auth state changes. I created a function that fetches the data and a state to store it:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

  const getUserData = async () => {
    const userRef = fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(fire.auth().currentUser.email);

    const doc = await userRef.get();
    let tempUser = doc.data();
    setUserData(tempUser);
  };
```

Then I have the listener:

```
  //AUTH STATE OBSERVER

  fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      getUserData()
    } else {
      console.log("user not logged in");
    }
  });
```

This starts an infinite loop. I can't seem to figure out why - to me it should only fire when the function once when auth state changes and the function should not affect auth state..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike normal observers, `onAuthStateChanged` will fire immediately with the current user state if it's available.

So on every render, you call the "listener" you are passing in which then retrieves the data, updates your state, causing a new render, which then repeats the process.

The correct way to listen for user data changes would be to use:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
  // If a user is already logged in, use the current User object, or `undefined` otherwise.
  return fire.auth().currentUser || undefined;
});
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

// keeps `user` up to date
useEffect(() => fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []);

// keeps `userData` up to date
useEffect(() => {
  if (user === null) {
    setUserData(null); // <-- clear data when not logged in
    return;
  }

  if (!user) {
    // user still loading, do nothing yet
    return;
  }

  return fire // <-- return the unsubscribe function from onSnapshot
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(fire.auth().currentUser.email)
    .onSnapshot({
      next(snapshot) {
        setUserData(snapshot.data());
      },
      error(err) {
        // TODO: handle errors
      }
    });
}, [user]); // <-- rerun when user changes
```